# How to prevent multiple queries by inlines in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-3.8, django-database

I fought with this all day yesterday, but can't really find a way out. I've got three models where A is related to C through B. The A-admin inlines B which has the FK to C.

The admin inlines are causing queries per item which is incredibly slow. Making the offending fields raw_id_only does help (readonly even further), but that is not what I'm trying to do.

I read in a few bug tickets, that this intended behaviour, because they don't want to keep the queryset for the choices in memory. But I do want that. Just I'm not sure where to start. I'd like to create a dict of all C (just id and **str** actually) in the A-admin once and then pass it to each of the inline admins forms instead of it causing another query. How could I pull this off?

Here is the ticket that describes the behaviour in detail:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31295

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your project is structured, but this sounds like it could be solved to adding [prefetch_related] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to the for either model B or model A somewhere in your code, either in the admin get_queryset method or in the ModelManager

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just as they describe in the ticket the formset of the inlines does not care for that.